# The function will not work if the parameter is the returning value of another function

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, return, undefined

Well, I've created the function bellow to return true or false based on the values that are passed as parameters. If the first parameter (region) is written manually the function will work as expected and will return true or false based on the value of the other two parameters. 
I am trying now to set the parameter's value based on the user's choice which comes as the value of a drop down. I've extracted the choice of the user with a function and then passed the returning value of that function (getUserImputForm()) as a parameter to the other one.

I have already tried to store the returning value of the getUserImputForm() in another variable and pass that instead as an argument to the other function. The result will not be false or true, only undefined. 
I thought as well that the problem may consist in the fact that the returning value is not sent in quotes as in 'America' and I've tried to return it as return "'" + e.target.value + "'". It still won't work.

```
const getUserInputForm = () => {
        const formSelector = document.querySelector('#select-region')
        formSelector.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
            console.log(e.target.value)
             return  e.target.value 
        })
    }


const match = async(region, country, capital) => {
        const allData = await countryesBringer(region)  

        const countryHere = ()=> {
            const countryCapitalArray = []

            allData.forEach((element)=> {
                countryCapitalArray.push(element.name.common, element.capital[0])
            })
            console.log(countryCapitalArray)
            // return countryArray.includes(country)
            for(var i = 0; i<countryCapitalArray.length; i++){
                const index = countryCapitalArray.indexOf(country)
                const capitalMatch = countryCapitalArray[index+1]
                if(capitalMatch === capital){
                    return true
                } else{
                    return false
                }
            }

            }
            const resolved = countryHere()
            console.log(resolved)
            return resolved
        }

    match('Americas', 'United States', 'Washington D.C.').then((value => {
        console.log(value)
    }))

    // The match function will run accordingly if 'Americas' is passed as the first argument, but will return undefined if getUserImputForm() is passed.
```

Comment: `getUserInputForm` doesn't return anything, it just adds an event listener.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it's all sorted. I should've called the match function inside the addEventListener function and pass the value that comes from it as the first arg.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mutate or validate or anything else with form data you can create form values object and work with it:

```
const formValues = {
  field1: undefined,
  field2: undefined,
};

const formSelector = document.querySelector('#select-region');
formSelector.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  formValues['select-region'] = e.target.value;
  proceedFunc();
});

const proceedFunc = () => {
  // manipulate formValues data here
};
```